# Gradle checksum policy

Tags: java, gradle

Maven has an option to control whether or not checksums are checked called checksum policy. Is there a way to skip checksums in Gradle?

It doesn't seem to be present in the documentation.

Comment: checksums of what? Question "Can I skip checksums?" does not have any sense :)

Comment: If you know how to use maven or gradle, you'll know what they are: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/